# I want to Join 4 tables in sql by which i can get Name,DepartmentID,CategoryName where email="abc@gmail.com"

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, join

I Have four tables

I Have four tables on the basis of the condition i want to fetch those columns

`Name,DepartmentID,CategoryName where Email="abc@gmail.com"`

Comment: **JOINS**...........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following SQL will work.

```
Select 
    u.Name, d.IDDepartment as DepartmentID,
    c.NameEn asCategoryNme 
from 
    Users u 
join 
    Usercategory uc on uc.IDUser = u.UserID 
join 
    Categories c on c.IDGroup = uc.IDGroup 
join 
    CompanyEmployees ce on ce.userid = u.UserID 
where 
    u.email = 'input email'
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to join four tables, you'd three `join` clauses, with their corresponding conditions:

```
SELECT u.Name, ce.IDDepartment, c.NameEn
FROM   Users u
JOIN   CompanyEmployees ce ON u.UserId = ce.IDUser
JOIN   UserCatrgory uc ON u.userId = uc.IDUser
JOIN   Categories C ON uc.IDGroup = c.IDDGroup
WHERE  u.Email = 'abc@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use join.

```
SELECT u.Name, d.IDDepartment, c.NameEr
FROM   Users u
       JOIN CompanyEmployees d ON u.UserId = d.IDUser
       JOIN UserCategory uc ON u.UserId = uc.IDUser
       JOIN Categories c ON uc.IDGroup = c.IDGroup 
where u.Email='abc@gmail.com'
```